# Logging Outside of Method Results in Empty ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` called `postArrayList`. Logging `postArrayList` inside `onComplete()` logs it correctly, but logging it outside the method results in `postArrayList` being 
empty. Why is this happening?

```
documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            if(task.getResult().exists()){
                postArrayList.add(post);
                Log.i("postArrayList", String.valueOf(postArrayList));
            }
        }
    }
});
Log.i("postArrayList1", String.valueOf(postArrayList));
```

Comment: Because your `onComplete` is called after your last line is executed. So, your `postArrayList` doesn't have any elements at that point.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to execute the onComplete method before executing the last line?